How to combine 2 datasets with different time stamps?
I have 2 datasets - one is raw sensor data from hydraulic pump and other data is the leakage data extracted from a simulation tool called AMESim. The time stamp of the raw data is fixed and is recorded at 30s interval but the simulated leakage data is extracted as 0 to 30, 30 to 60s ... So there are values between these intervals. I'm really confused how to combine these two dataset and use it for deep learning model training ?
I don't want to aggregate the leakage data because for times series modeling I need all the info from the dataset.
If anyone has got an idea for this please do let me know ?
I tried to repeat the raw data to match the time stamp of the leakage data. But I'm not sure whether this is a good approach also.
